# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference with foreign key on razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, model

This is my model

```
public class Appointment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public Patient patient { get; set; }
    ...
}
...
public class Patient
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cin { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public User doctor { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to show the patient name for each of the doctor's appointments in razor

```
foreach (var appointment in date)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@appointment.patient.name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

But I get this error :

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

It works with all other properties (id, start, end) but not with patient, which is a foreign key

**UPDATE**

This is the function that returns the appointments

```
public dynamic appointments()
{
    Database db = new Database();
    var query = db.Appointments.Where(a => a.patient.doctor == this).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(a => a.start.Date);
    var appointments = query.ToList();
    return appointments;
}
```

The appointments are grouped by each date, and this is how they are displayed in view

```
foreach (var date in ViewBag.Appointments)
@{
    <h3><b>@date.Key.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</b></h3>
    <table>
        foreach (var appointment in date)
        @{
            <tr>
                <td>@appointment.patient.name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Add your action method code to the post, please. And how are declaring the view model?

Comment: @Jackdaw its too long to post, as the appointments are grouped by date. But I will post the function that returns the appointments

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your model

```
public class Appointment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
   ....
     public int? patientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient patient { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Patient
{
    public int id { get; set; }
     ....
      public int? doctorId { get; set; }
      public virtual User doctor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Appointment> appointments { get; set; }

}
```

and get appointments

```
public List<Appointment> appointments()
{
    Database db = new Database();
   return = db.Appointments
         .Include(p=> p.Patient)
         .Where(a => a.patient.doctorId == doctorId)
                  //or maybe a.patient.doctorId == this.doctorId I don't 
                    know what is "this"
          .GroupBy(a => a.start.Date)
          .ToList();
 
}
```

but mybe it is more effective to add PatientName property to Appointment

```
[NotMapped]
public string PatientName {get; set;}
```

in this case you don't need  to return the whole Patient class

```
var appointments = db.Appointments
         .Include(p=> p.Patient)
         .Where(a => a.patient.doctorId == doctorId)
                  //or maybe a.patient.doctorId == this.doctorId I don't 
                    know what is "this"
          .GroupBy(a => a.start.Date)
          .ToList();

  foreach( var i=0; i< appointments.Count; i+=1)
{
     appointment[i].PatientName=list[i].Patient.Name;
     appointment[i].Patient=null;
}
 return appointements;
```

or maybe just this:

```
public List<string> appointmentNames()
{
    Database db = new Database();
   return = db.Appointments
           .Where(a => a.patient.doctorId == doctorId)
                  //or maybe a.patient.doctorId == this.doctorId I don't 
                    know what is "this"
          .GroupBy(a => a.start.Date)
          .Select (a=> a.Patient.Name)
          .ToList();
 
}
```